# What is the advantage of using smaller OFDMA subcarrier spacing?

Tags: wireless-networking, cellular-internet

This will require a bit of an ELI5, but what's the advantage of using smaller sub-carriers in different implementations of OFDMA?

In 802.11 ac (OFDM) the subcarrier spacing was 312.5 kHz. In 802.11 ax it is 1/4th of that, 78.125 kHz. In LTE it's only 15 kHz. In 5G, it can be 15, 30, 60, 120, or 240 kHz.

Other than having more "fine" control over resource allocation (assuming smaller resources units as well), what's the advantage of using smaller sub-carriers? Does it increase your throughput? How so?

What's the disadvantage, more potential intersymbol interference, hence a higher SNR requirement?

Please explain your terms a bit if possible, if you bring up things like symbol length or equalization, I don't quite understand those concepts.

Comment: Probably smaller carriers mean wider bandwidth for the main data signal and less wasted frequencies. The downside is probably that it requires better quality recevers that can more precisely track narrower bandwidth signals resulting in a possible cost increase. Only guesses though.

Comment: This question isn’t really suitable for Super User. Simply put, SU is for solving computer problems. This isn’t one. I’m not sure there _is_ a Stack Exchange site for this.

Comment: Thanks. I will say though, that I have searched this site and there are hundreds of ELI5 "explain basic concept related to computer science" questions, it seems more like Quora than a place for seeking help with specific computer-related problems. In fact the reason I came here is because it seems to be better at ELI5 than ELI5 itself. I guess I'll look for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Every subcarrier carries additional bits of data, so the more you can cram in there, the more throughput you get.

If a farmer can reduce the spacing between rows in his field, he can cram in more rows, meaning more plants, meaning higher yields per acre (hopefully).

And yes, making the transmission more complex makes it harder to decode, including harder to separate signal from noise, so higher throughputs generally require higher SNRs.